# Time stamp automatically update when update any field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

suppose i have a table called user like this

```
╔════╦══════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id ║   key    ║       keytime       ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ somekey1 ║ 2016-01-01 15:39:43 ║
║  2 ║ somekey2 ║ 2016-01-02 15:39:43 ║
╚════╩══════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

the **keytime** field type is TIMESTAMP and default value is **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**

How to update **keytime** field automatically when I update key field

```
UPDATE `user` 
SET `Key` = '2' 
WHERE `id` = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ALTER TABLE `user` 
   MODIFY keytime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

to make it update automatically.

See [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: Come on. That is not that hard. :-) Just google *alter mysql table*.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `user` CHANGE `keyime` `keyime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;       working well thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE `user`(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                   `key` VARCHAR(100),
                   keytime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO `user`(`key`, keytime) VALUES ('key', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 10000);

CREATE TRIGGER user_update 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `user` 
FOR EACH ROW 
   SET NEW.keytime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

UPDATE `user` 
SET `Key` = '2' 
WHERE `id` = 1;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05119/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your example